# Rotate image_button

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a image button

```
   <asp:ImageButton
    ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/ImgTest.png" 
    CssClass="test" onclick="ImageButton1_Click"  />
```

And I need to turn it for 45 degrees.

```
.test {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
}

   /\****
  /  \***
 /    \**
/      \*
\      /*
 \    /**
  \  /***
   \/****
```

The problem is, I need to button_Click only inside cube, for a moment I can click in * area, but I should remove it.

What ways have to remove Click from ** area ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this - based on `CausesValidation` property

```
ImageButton.CausesValidation="false"
```

So

```
<asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" .../>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.causesvalidation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to try an HTML image map.  [Coffee cup](http://www.coffeecup.com/image-mapper/) is a slick tool that makes these easy.